# Binary Search Tree balancing by rotation (on AVL tree)

Tags: binary-search-tree

I'm wondering, is there only ONE possible outcome for the final balanced Binary Search Tree? Sometimes I get different final balanced tree depending on where I do the rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There several self balancing types of trees, most popular are AVL and Red-Black. If you put same data in those trees, the resulting trees would be different, yet balanced.

If speaking about AVL tree, I will just give simple example:

```
   2     |      4     |      3     
 1   4   |    2   5   |    2   4   
    3 5  |   1 3      |   1     5
```

All of them are balanced AVL trees, that can be created by different orders of operations.
But if you repeat the same order of operations with exactly same data, resulting trees should be the same, because there is nothing probabilistic in AVL tree algorithm.

Comment: Here I have an AVL Tree, and I was asked to perform Insert operations, and a delete operation. Depending on where I do rotation, I get different answers. Are you suggesting that this is normal?

Comment: @stackplasm, sorry, I didn't read your question carefully, I will try to answer the actual question in a moment.